# SMS from Android device to C# application on computer

Tags: c#, android, .net, sms, adb

I want to make a fullscreen application that can display the latest messages received on the Android device (an SMS wall).

I've tried pulling the MMSSMS.db file from the device with ADB, but the file can't be read on my computer. It seems like it's encrypted or something, because on the phone itself you can open and view it.

Is there any library or other solution available that can accomplish that? I've searched a lot and didn't find anything on the web...

Edit: i've tried using the sqlite.dll both with SQLite Browser and in C# itself. Both showed an empty database while it was readable (and not empty) in the built-in Database Viewer of Root Explorer.

I am not specifically asking for third-party libraries or tools, only if someone has had any experience with this and/or can help me further...

Edit 2: I came here only when I didn't find a solution after searching a lot on the web.

Thanks!

Comment: I imagine that its a database file, most likely sqlite.

Comment: Asking any third party tools/library/off-site resource isn't appreciable here. Instead try to search by your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that its a database file, most likely sqlite. You need to install a library to address such a file. http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki